# Include a Folder in ClickOnce Application

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, clickonce, publish

I've created a Windows C# project and made it as **ClickOnce** Application(Publish feature in Project properties) for Installation.
I want to *Include a folder* which has Crystal Report (rpt) files in it. In my application I have given path of rpt file as my Installation location.
How can I include this folder while publish. So that I need not copy the folder manually.

Comment: @M.Babcock I guess Microsoft because of the use of c# here.

Comment: @itzArun - Marking the files in the folder as resources doesn't automagically include them in the deployment?

Comment: yes it is ClickOnce of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Application.

Comment: @M.Babcock but how can I mark the crystal report file into resources?

Comment: @itzArun - Add the files to the project, select the file in the Solution Explorer and then change the file's Build Action (in the file's properties) to "Resource".

Comment: That too not copying the file into the installation directory.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to add the items to the project and mark them as 'Content' (select the item in solution explorer, right click, properties, set Build Action).

Comment: This won't create the needed folder though.  The files are included in the program directory, but if you need the folder created how would you do that?

Comment: @Patratacus: The files must be added under the folders where they should be placed after installation. This will create the folders. One more thing left: make sure you change the publish status column to the added files in the Application Files dialog to Include, as opposed to Include (Auto). See [this](http://devrecipeshb.blogspot.co.il/2018/02/adding-files-and-folders-to-click-once.html).

Answer (score 28):

So Tom has explained how to add a file. You specifically say you would like to add a folder to your ClickOnce application once you publish it. Lets assume you have a folder sitting in the root of your solution named `Dependencies` which contains a folder `Reports` which contains all of your RPT files. Here is how you would make sure your deployed app contains all of the contents of the `Dependencies` folder:

1. Right click your project in Visual Studio and select "unload project".
2. Right click and select to edit the csproj file.
3. Before the closing `</Project>` tag add this:

   `<ItemGroup>`
       `<Content Include="$(SolutionDir)Dependencies\**\*">`
         `<Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>`
         `<Visible>false</Visible>`
       `</Content>`
     `</ItemGroup>`
4. That will add everything from the Dependencies folder into the project. We are using the `\**\*` syntax at the end of the Include and `%(RecursiveDir)` to ensure the `Reports` folder will be present in the published version as well as the report files. Having set `<Visible>false</Visible>` you won't see the items cluttering up the solution explorer.

Comment: You Sir just saved me a lot of wasted time. Thanks for the detailed description!

Comment: How do I copy the entire directory, not only its contentes into the Project. For example, have _the_ `foo` folder presente in the ClickOnce application folder.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that we have two projects: main - `ProjectA` and some other `ProjectB` referencing `ProjectA`. In `ProjectB` we have a folder `FolderB` with some files that should be included when publishing (pdf, rpt, etc.) `ProjectA`.

Once we build `ProjectA` there will be all referenced files and folders in the `bin` directory. But when we publish the solution using the ClickOnce tool, the folders from the referenced `ProjectB` won't be included in the installer and you won't see them in the `Application Files` window in the project publish settings.

The solution for this issue is to create a new folder called `FolderB` in `ProjectA` and add the existing items from `FolderB` in `ProjectB` to this new folder in `ProjectA` using the ***Add As Link*** option. Then all the files, including the files linked from the `ProjectB` folders, will be included when publishing of `ProjectA`.

Comment: this helped me more than the others! many thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since the OP, but when I add a folder to my solution, add a Crystal Report to that folder and mark it as "Content" (per Tom), then Publish and install - the folder and report gets added to the ClickOnce installation location. So Tom's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Barrie has the best solution, really solves all I needed! No need to include same files in multiple projects, just setup pre-build event that copies files in debug for local functionality and debugging. Solves my problem with rdlc (reports) having in one location and using them in multiple projects.