# Tesseract ClickOnce Deployment fails

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce, tesseract

I am using the tesseract OCR recognition for a small research project. Running and testing it locally works fine. Unfortunately, I have problems with the deployment (WPF ClickOnce-Deployment) when I use the [Tesseract OCR .NET Wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract). I get the following error when I run my progrm (after installing it):

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at InteropDotNet.InteropRuntimeImplementer.CreateInstance[T]()
   at Tesseract.Interop.LeptonicaApi.Initialize()
   at Tesseract.Interop.TessApi.Initialize()
   at Tesseract.Interop.TessApi.get_Native()
   at Tesseract.TesseractEngine..ctor(String datapath, String language, EngineMode engineMode)
   at WindowsContextTracker.Helpers.OcrEngine..ctor()
   at WindowsContextTracker.Helpers.OcrEngine.GetInstance()
   at WindowsContextTracker.Daemon.RunContextRecognition(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

My code:

```
var path = @"C:\ProgramData\myProgram\tessdata";
_tEngine = new TesseractEngine(path, "eng", EngineMode.Default);
```

I tried [various combinations of the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067002/tesseract-3-ocr-net-wrapper) (dynamically, statically). At the location of the path, there is a directory, tessdata, that includes 9 files (eng.cube.bigrams, eng.traineddata, etc.).

I would be very thankful for any hint leading towards solving my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I didn't find a good solution for my problem. WPF ClickOnceDeployments are always stored in a 'temporary' folder in the user's `AppData`. This is the folder, where you also need to (manually) copy the `tessdata` folder in order to make the tesseract api work. Then, you also don't need to add a path to the `tessdata` folder anymore. It seems to me as if this path doesn't work...

This is not really a solution, but the only way I found to make it run... So if you know a better way, please let me know!

**Edit**: Thanks to Sicos1977 (on [Github](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/issues/162)), I found a solution to this second problem. He pointed me to a Stackoverflow [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656633/include-a-folder-in-clickonce-application) where I learnt how to copy a whole folder during the installation to the installation location.